# Angular reactive form - Disable material design buttons in FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form containing Angular material design components. I want to disable all controls in the form while the component is being initialized<sup>1</sup>.

I have tried to call disable() on the FormGroup in the constructor as well as in ngOnInit(), but for some reason buttons (using material design) in the form remains enabled.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dcrkc3)

The template:

```
<form [formGroup]="emailForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email" />
  </mat-form-field>
  <button formControlName="removeButton" mat-icon-button class="button-small" (click)="clearEmail()" matTooltip="Clear email address" matTooltipClass="tooltip-medium" [matTooltipShowDelay]="500" ngDefaultControl>
    <mat-icon aria-label="Clear">clear</mat-icon>
  </button>
</form>
```

The component:

```
export class EmailFormComponent implements OnInit {
  private emailForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formbBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.createReactiveForm();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.emailForm.disable();
  }  

  createReactiveForm() {
    this.emailForm  = this.formbBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.email, Validators.maxLength(100)]],
      removeButton : ['']
    });

    this.emailForm.disable();
  }

  clearEmail() {
    this.emailForm.patchValue({email:''});
  }
}
```

If I remove material design from the button it gets disabled during initialization. If I call `this.emailform.disable()`from a click eventHandler method in the component the button in the form also gets disabled.

Is it a bug that the button doesn't get disabled during initialization or am I doing something wrong? How do I make the button disabled in the UI at initialization?

(Note: This is a simplified example. The real application has more input fields in the form).

<sup>1</sup> When I asked this question I was unfamiliar with Angular's [resolve guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data) which can be used to load dynamic data before navigating to a component.

Comment: Can you make sure that the stackblitz you provided was working?? For me it is showing not found.. Hope this https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-reactive-form-vnjkia    helps..

Comment: Thanks for noticing. Please try again now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use form control for button. Just disable form and use button disabling like:

```
<button [disabled]="emailForm.disabled" ...
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tshueb)